# Integração de site com planilha Excel

Tags: html, banco-de-dados, asp.net-mvc-5, microsoft-excel

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível usar uma planilha excel já configurada com fórmulas e registros como um "banco de dados" de um site.

A intenção é que a pessoa acesse à página, insira os dados e envia-los para essa planilha. Com isso acredito que seria necessário deixar essa planilha hospedada para que a página tivesse acesso a ela.

Enfim, poderiam me auxiliar nessa questão?

Comment: Sua aplicação possui banco de dados?

Comment: A dúvida seria se é possível usar a planilha como banco de dados

Comment: Possível até seria, mas não vejo nenhuma vantagem em usar uma planilha ao invés de um banco de dados "normal'. Você perderia muito em questões de consulta, por exemplo, ao fazer uma gambiarra destas.

Comment: Entendi, e porque como já existe uma planilha pronta com formulas estava pensando em usá-la, mas não sabia ao certo se perdia muito com isso.